# How to serve Flask app on different port than main site running on port 80?

Tags: flask

Read through the other threads, but none seemed to address my need.

I have a website running fine on default port 80/443 using Apache on CentOS 7.

I have now installed gunicorn and copied my files to a /api subdirectory on the server. I am able to start gunicorn successfully using "gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 api:app"; however, I don't seem to be able to browse to https://example.com:8000 (site can't be reached).

Do I need to use a VirtualHost's file specifically for the Flask /api directory? If so, what would that look like without disrupting the main site?

EDIT: Note this is a Flask-RESTful API, no static files or anything on the Flask side. Just endpoints/routes to serve.

Comment: If you run with flask development server (no gunicorn) does it work as expected?

Comment: I have a site running on port 80 and 443 (80 redirects to https version of site). When I run the gunicorn command, it works in console, and allows even specifiying the "host" and "port" options as well. I'm not able to work out any working URL in the browser for it though. The main site continues to work throughout.

Comment: Was about to open the same question and realized I asked this almost a year ago! No resolution still. Anyone have any ideas on this?